# Linq to DataTable query missing the first record in result set

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

```
DateTime start = d.Key; // say 2013-06-01
DateTime end = d.Key.AddDays(d.Value); // say end=2013-06-07

var filteredRecords = from n in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      orderby n["Date"] ascending
                      where (DateTime)n["Date"] >= start && (DateTime)n["Date"] <= end
                      select n;
```

The Query works fine but it's always missing the first record i.e. data for first date (2013-06-01). I've checked it with database and there I'm getting data for the missing date. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `d`? Are you sure the value of `d.Key` is exactly `2013-06-01`? I mean there may be parts of minutes and seconds? The same logic applied to `n["Date"]`...

Comment: d is a Dictionary<DateTime,int> object. Yes it's 2013-06-01,  I've checked it visual studio using breakpoints.

Comment: You should tried extracting the value from the first record and comparing it with `d.Key` to see if they match each other. If not, that's the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use only `Date` part of your dates for comparison:

```
from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
let date = r.Field<DateTime>("Date")
where date.Date >= start.Date && date.Date <= end.Date
orderby date ascending
select r;
```

Comment: **Awesome, that works perfecct lazyberezovsky Sir** Thanks a ton, saved my day :)

Comment: +1 for `let date = ...`. One of the big benefits of query syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
var recs = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x=>x.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= start && x.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= end)
                         .OrderBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date"));
```